# Как определить точные координаты пользователя без использования GPS и интернет

Tags: php, javascript, java, c#, 3g

Я хочу определить точные координаты пользователя с помощью базовых станций провайдера, т.е на уровне 2G или 3G.

На данный момент у меня есть только широта и долгота каждой Базовой станции на карте. Если найти пользователя то я могу сказать только, что этот пользователь обслуживается только на определенной Базовой станции и все.

Я хочу создать веб-проект типа Онлайн мониторинг определенного пользователя на карте Google Map, т.е куда он движется и где он.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим вопросом? И что лучше использовать для создания данного веб-проекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вспомнить основы радиосвязи, то имея полный доступ к базовым станциям, такое теоретически возможно.

Каждая станция, прежде чем подключить клиента, определяет уровень сигнала от клиента. Сотовая связь по идее должна быть устроена так, что пользователя, точнее его мобильное устройство, "видят" одновременно несколько станций. Для определения положения нужно минимум три станции. Далее триангулируем положение пользователя по уровню сигнала. Примерно так работает A-GPS.

НО:

1. Точность будет отвратительная, я сам наблюдал как мой навигатор показывал что я нахожусь в 2-3 км от моего реально положения, благо местность я знал и без навигатора.
2. Улучшить точность не получится, так как GSM использует гигагерцовый диапазон частот, который работает только в зоне прямой видимости между приемником и передатчиком, а это значит что любая железо-бетонная или металлическая конструкция или мощный источник электромагнитного поля вроде ЛЭП будут вносить существенные искажения в показания мощности сигнала пользователя.
3. Нужен полный доступ к программной начинке базовых станций, без которого получить уровни сигнала мне не представляется возможным. Такой доступ по идее должен быть только у операторов связи.

Comment: Так на телефоне тоже можно наверное определить мощность сигнала от конкретной станции?

Comment: @OlegUP В теории да, 2й пункт все равно все нещадно портит, а при условии отсутствия интернета, как просит автор, как передать полученные сведения в сервис?

Comment: У меня есть полный доступ у операторов связи, используется технология Huawei. А вот выше как вы указали методом триангуляцией. А вот тоже где то прочитал что технология GPS так и работает, но не знаю есть ли возможность реализовать на уровне 2G или 3G, и вообще у какой  нибудь сотовых провайдеров реализован он или нет?

Comment: @MuhammadYakubov к сожалению, мои познания в этом вопросе ограничены только теорией... но похоже что как-то реализовано, только доступ к этой системе есть только у спец. служб, т.к. она, в теории, позволяет следить за пользователем без его ведома.

Comment: Если есть координаты GPS каждой базовой станции еще, то можно обучить программу пользоватья достаточно подробными картами google, у каждой преграды сигнала могут быть различия коеффициента помех в зависимости от его свойств, конечно может быть я пишу бред, просто делюсь идеей для развития. То есть собрать в зоне досягаемости станции информацию о помехах, и каким либо образом сравнить с ее мощностью сигнала, и мощностью других станций и их зонами помех, можно также опираться на том методе который у вас есть, а  уже потом зная приблизитеольное положение - более оптимально высчитывать помехи.

Comment: @OlegUP ну почему же, совсем не бред? просто чтобы все это проделать нужен далеко не один разработчик, а инженерный отдел для проведения измерений на местности, сбора и анализа технической информации, расчетов и т.д. ну и программистов парочку сверху =) И это только на один небольшой город. дороговато выходит

Comment: @OlegUP плюс, очередная высотная новостройка и все по новой для учета изменившихся условий.

Comment: @rdorn зачем, когда есть машинное обучение?

Answer (score 0):

Если есть доступ к данным о том, какие базовые станции "видит" телефон и время отклика от них, то задача тривиальна, если такой информации нет, то без GPS - никак.

Comment: телефон ничего не видит, он посылает запрос, вроде UTP бродкаста всем кто "увидит", а дальше система станций сама "ведет" его от станции к станции предавая по мере уменьшения сигнала на одной и увеличения на другой.